# Alive neighbour cells not correctly counted

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

I know my title isn't very specific but that's because I have no idea where the problem comes from. I'm stuck with this problem since 2 or 3 hours and in theory everything should be working, but it's not.
This piece of code:

```
for ( int x = -1; x <= 1; x++ ) {       //Iterate through the 8 neighbour cells plus the one indicated
    for ( int y = -1; y <= 1; y++ ) {

        neighbour = coords(locX + x, locY + y, width);      //Get the cell index in the array

        if (existsInOrtho(ortho, neighbour)) {      //If the index exists in the array

            if (ortho[neighbour] == 0) {        //Cell is dead
                cnt--;      //Remove one from the number of alive neighbour cells
            }

        } else {        //Cell is not in the zone
            cnt--;      //Remove one from the number of alive neighbour cells
        }

    }
}
```

Iterates through all the neighbour cells to get their value in the array (1 for alive, 0 for dead). The "coords" function, shown here:

```
int coords(int locX, int locY, int width)
{
    int res = -1;

    locX = locX - 1;    //Remove one from both coordinates, since an index    starts at 0 (and the zone starts at (1;1) )
    locY = locY - 1;

    res = locX * width + locY;      //Small calculation to get the index of the pixel in the array

    return res;
}
```

Gets the index of the cell in the array. But when I run the code, it doesn't work, the number of neighbour cells is not correct (it's like a cell is not counted every time there's some alive in the neighborhood). I tried decomposing everything manually, and it works, so I don't know what ruins everything in the final code... [Here is the complete code.](https://pastebin.com/wRdbtz0h) Sorry if I made any English mistake, it's not my native language.

Comment: `locX = locX - 1; ` Why are you doing this? You loop from -1 to 1 on both x and y, and which will cover all surrounding cells (including the cell itself when `x == 0 && y == 0`, which you probably dont want).

Comment: Because the coordinates starts at (1;1) and not (0;0). And I know I'm counting the cell itself, that's why I assumed in the entire code that there were 9 alive neighbour cells.

Comment: I dont really understand your code, but a common mistake is to count the neighbors and update cells in the same array. You need a temp array for the next timestep and only copy it once you passed all cells

Comment: Oh god I think that's it... It would make sense. I'm going to try this.

Comment: Oh well, it works. Thank you so much !

Comment: Is there no duplicate for "use two arrays for game of life"? If there actually is none, please either make an answer or delete this question, in order to get it out of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code ...

```
for ( int x = -1; x <= 1; x++ ) {       //Iterate through the 8 neighbour cells plus the one indicated
    for ( int y = -1; y <= 1; y++ ) {
```

Actually checks **9** cells.  Perhaps you forgot that it checks (x,y) = (0,0).  That would include the cell itself as well as its neighbours.

A simple fix is:

```
for ( int x = -1; x <= 1; x++ ) {       //Iterate through the 8 neighbour cells plus the one indicated
    for ( int y = -1; y <= 1; y++ ) {
        if (x || y) {
```

Also, the `simulate` function (from your link) makes the common mistake of updating the value of the cell in the same array before processing state changes required for the cells beside it.  The easiest fix is to keep two arrays -- two complete copies of the grid (two `ortho` arrays, in your code).  When reading from orthoA, update orthoB.  And then on the next generation, flip.  Read from orthoB and write to orthoA.

Comment: Look on my post's comment, the problem has already been fixed. And the 9 cells checking is normal. I needed to create a temporary array.

Comment: Don't you mean `if (x || y)` ?